# Trying to translate AES CTR decrypting Python code to java

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes

This is the code in question:

```
decrypt(self):
    """Decrypt one block"""
    data = self.source.read(1024)
    if not data:
        return ""
    iv = data[:16]
    encrypted = data[16:]
    counter = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(64, prefix=iv[:8], initial_value=struct.unpack(">Q", iv[8:])[0])
    cipher = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(self.info["CpData"], Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_CTR, counter=counter)
    return cipher.decrypt(encrypted)
```

This is the line I have problems understanding:

```
counter = Crypto.Util.Counter.new(64, prefix=iv[:8], initial_value=struct.unpack(">Q", iv[8:])[0])
```

What does it do and how do I replicate it in Java? Currently I have this, but the result is not what I expect:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding"); 

    byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedData, 0, 16) ; // first 16 bytes
    byte[] data = Arrays.copyOfRange(encryptedData, 16, 1024); // rest

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(data);
    return decValue;
}
```

Hours of googling have not yielded a useable result. How do I use this counter thing in Java?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a quick look it appears that there is 8 bytes of IV prepended to the incoming cyphertext.  Extract the first 8 bytes and use them as an IV to set up AES-CTR.  Then decrypt the rest of the cyphertext.